# Non-homogeneous bessel recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, bessel-functions

I found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_general_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations) that the first kind of the bessel functions obey the following homogeneous second order difference equation:

$$J_{n+1}(z) = \frac{2n}{z}J_{n}(z) - J_{n-1}(z)$$
Now, I'm trying to find an explicit solution for the non-homogeneous form of this difference equation(k>1):
$$c_{k+1} = \frac{2k}{\alpha}c_{k}  -c_{k-1} + a \cdot J_{k}(z) $$
With $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ and $J_{k}(z)$ the bessel function of first kind, evaluated in $z\in \mathbb{C}$

Even though this equation may look daunting, my intuition tells me that it cannot be a coincidence that I have this bessel function as the non-homogeneous part. Since the homogeneous part is the bessel function of first kind(given by the equation above), finding a particular solution is sufficient. But I unfortunately couldn't find any good candidate(if there is one).

Someone who can help?